# TFS 2018 - Cannot use the Search function

Tags: tfs

I used to use the "Search" function in TFS 2018 but suddenly I got an error when I tried to use it.

[image]

Any idea how to fix it?

Edit:

- I have over 60GB of disk free space in TFS Server.
- Elastic Search 2.4.1 is up and running.
- I've looked into Microsoft documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/project/search/administration?view=azure-devops#no-results-later).
  This is the result I get when I access the search server (localhost:9200) from a web browser on a computer in the same domain as the server running Search:

[image]

If I access http://localhost:9200/_cat/health?v I get this:

[image]

I've checked and elastic search is running.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

If it worked before and suddenly stopped the first thing I would do it's to check the Code Search server disk space. this issue happened to me in the past and the reason was that the disks was full.

If the disks space are OK, open the services and check if Elastic Search service (`elasticsearch-service-x64`) is running.

If the service is running you can try the following steps:

1) Access the URL `http://CodeSearchServer:9200` from the browser:

- If the status returned is `200 - OK`, go step 2.
- If any other status is returned, contact MS support.

2) If the status is 200, access the URL `http://CodeSearchServer:9200/_cat/health?v`.

- If the status columns shows green/OK, contact MS support.
- If the status column shows red/fault, look at the value in the `init` or `unassigned` columns. if these are greater than zero, wait for 30 minuets and then repeat this step. if the values are unchanged go step 3.

3) Access the URL `http://CodeSearchServer:9200/_cat/shards?v`.

- Make a note of the values in the Shard columns for the rows with a `state` value of `unassigned` and contact MS support.

More info you can find [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/project/search/administration?view=azure-devops#troubleshoot-search-in-azure-devops-server-and-tfs).

Comment: Hello. My search server is localhost:9200. I am not sure if it's relevant but if I try to access it changing localhost with the hostname I cannot access it.

Comment: So login to the code search server and use `localhost`

Comment: Please edit your question and not post it as an answer. did you check the disk spaces?

Comment: Ok. yes. I have 62 GB free in the Server.

Comment: Do you can't search anything?

Comment: No, I cannot search anything. I tried and for every search I get that error message.

Comment: Did you try to restart the elastic service?

Comment: Not yet but I can try.